# Sprite kit create a sprite without physical body

Tags: game-physics, sprite-kit

Can I create a sprite in physical world, without effected by physics,
or without a physical body which mean will not collide, or push other sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That is the standard behavior if you don't assign a `SKPhysicsBody` instance to the sprite's `physicsBody` property.